# How would you specify a conditional logistic regression with tidymodels

Tags: tidymodels

I'm interested in creating a model specification with tidymodels for conditional logistic regression. This is for a scenario like a track and field 1-Mile race where you might have a race with n runners and you want to know the probability of each runner winning the race.  Accordingly, the condition would be the sum of probabilities of all runners equals 1.

I've specified logistic regression models in tidymodels, but I'm not sure how I would specify conditional logistic regression model.

Comment: We don't currently support conditional logistic regression in tidymodels. If you would like to describe a) a base R implementation you like to use and b) the contexts you like to use this in [in a GitHub issue for parsnip](https://github.com/tidymodels/parsnip/issues), that would be super helpful for prioritization.

Comment: I guess what you are trying to do is a multi-class classification, where the number of classes is the number of runners. In this case, the prediction output is the probability of each class, which, by definition, sums up to 1. In tidymodels, you use `multinom_reg()` for the multi-class classification.